# El valor de la variable, no perdura

Tags: angular, typescript, timer

Estoy obteniendo un **TOKEN** de una API. Para ello uso un `get().subscribe...` en el **subscribe** el TOKEN ya se obtiene, pero en el `return` ya no existe el valor.

Clase

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class Service {
...
}
```

```
getAPIKey() {
    let token: string;
    const urlServer = `https://url.com`;
    this.http.get(urlServer).subscribe((data) => {
      token = data[`access_token`];
    });    
    return token;
}
```

y al llamar esta **función**, en la función **getQuery** me retorna **undefined**

```
getQuery(query: string) {
    let token: string;
    setTimeout(() => {
      token = this.getAPIKey();
    }, 5000);
    //3600000
    const url = `https://api.com/${query}`;
    console.log(`consulta `, url);
    const autorizacionAutomatico = `"Bearer ${token}"`;
    console.log(`Autorizacion `, autorizacionAutomatico);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: autorizacionAutomatico,
    });
    return this.http.get(url, { headers });
}
```

El porque hay 2 funciones es simple la primera obtiene el **TOKEN** y la segunda funciona como autorización para las consultas.

La URL `https://api.com/${query}` es parcial, hay otras funciones que completa esta con: `lugares`, `comida`, `población`.

De forma que:

1. Obtiene el TOKEN
2. Genera el headers con el TOKEN
3. Completa la URL, con la función `comida`

Pero técnicamente no llego ni a completar el paso 1. Porque fuera del `subscribe` parece que se pierde el valor. Me comentaron algo de que se ejecutan en cierto orden, lo que hace que obtenga el **token** pero se pierde por que la siguiente ejecución es... (no recuerdo, fue hace un tiempo ya y sigo sin encontrar una solución).

PD: la sentencia `setTimeout` esta ahí porque el token pierde su uso cada 1h. En fin espero haber sido, claro.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que los [Observables](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable) no se comportan como funciones síncronas, por lo que lo más probable es que la función retorne `token` antes de que este sea reasignado.

Ahora, hay más de una forma de solucionar esto. Sin embarqgo, tendrás que hacer uso de un flujo asíncrono. Por ejemplo:

```js
async getAPIKey() {
    const urlServer = `https://url.com`;
    return (await this.http.get(urlServer).toPromise()).access_token;
}
```

O:

```js
async getAPIKey() {
    const urlServer = `https://url.com`;
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
       this.http.get(urlServer).subscribe((data) => {
           resolve(data.access_token);
       });
    }).unsubscribe();
}
```

Evidentemente, se entiende que estas soluciones no están controlando posibles excepciones o errores. Por lo que han de requerir del uso del método [catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) donde de implementen.

Por otro lado, si lo que **necesitas** es trabajar exclusivamente con Observables, te recomiendo usar una propedad de la clase con la que estás trabajando (en tanto esta sea un componente o directiva de Angular. Por ejemplo:

```js
@Component({ ... })
export class ClaseNoEspecificadaEnElProblema {
    private token!: string | undefined;

    constructor (
        private readonly http: HttpClient,
    ) {}
    
    getAPIKey() {
        const urlServer = 'https://url.com';
        this.http.get(urlServer).subscribe(data => {
            this.token = data.access_token;
        }).unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: no, no hace falta trabajar con Observable, siempre que funciones pero... sigue igual, ya habia usado **async** pero con el respectivo `catch((e) => console.error(e));` pero me da el mismo resultado, fuera de la funcion `async` se pierde el valor. Acabo de agregar la clase

Comment: Cuidado con la segunda función. ya que, aunque mencionas que el token se ha de renovar cada hora (aunque en la función lo inicializas en 5 segundos de instanciada la función), en principio no asignas un valor. En el código está declarado como `let token: string;`, lo cual se traduce en un objeto `undefined`

Comment: lo del tiempo era solo para ver si funcionaba. `let token: string;` es `undefined` ya veo, gracias. Pero xq en los `console` la 1ra salida, tiene valor; la 2da es `undefined` por eso mi duda es xq no perdura, fuera dl `subscribe` lo mismo usando `async`. Quizá la cuestión esta en como definir la variable... no sé, ya sin ideas

Comment: Por otro lado, ya que estás trabajando con un servicio, lo que te recomiendo es trabajar con asíncronos. Qué es lo que intentaste concretamente con este método?

Comment: la función de **TOKEN** la deje es aparte porque tiene 1h de vigencia y la de la función `getQuery` más que de consulta es la que prepara el encabezado de lo que se quiere consultar. Ejm: `token: aazsxdc`; `url: https://url.com/comidaAutorizacion%20Bearer%20aazsxdc` (algo así la URL completa). Es independiente el `token` para evitar varias consultas al `API`.